# What is the proper way to do seed mongoDB in NestJS, using mongoose and taking advantage of my already defined schmas

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

We are using NestJS with mongoose and want to seed mongoDB.
Wondering what is the proper way to seed the database, and use the db schemas already defined to ensure the data seeded is valid and properly maintained.

Seeding at the module level (just before the definition of the Module) feels hacky and ends in threadpool being destroyed, and therefore all following mongo operations fail

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33186199/how-to-seed-dependent-data-in-node-mongodb

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've done using the nestjs-command library like that.

### 1. Install the library:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-command

### 2. Then I've created a command to seed my userService like:

> src/modules/user/seeds/user.seed.ts

```
import { Command, Positional } from 'nestjs-command';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

import { UserService } from '../../../shared/services/user.service';

@Injectable()
export class UserSeed {
constructor(
    private readonly userService: UserService,
) { }

@Command({ command: 'create:user', describe: 'create a user', autoExit: true })
async create() {
    const user = await this.userService.create({
        firstName: 'First name',
        lastName: 'Last name',
        mobile: 999999999,
        email: 'test@test.com',
        password: 'foo_b@r',
    });
    console.log(user);
}
}
```

### 3. Add that seed command into your module. I've created a SeedsModule in a shared folder to add more seeds in future

> src/shared/seeds.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CommandModule } from 'nestjs-command';

import { UserSeed } from '../modules/user/seeds/user.seed';
import { SharedModule } from './shared.module';

@Module({
    imports: [CommandModule, SharedModule],
    providers: [UserSeed],
    exports: [UserSeed],
})
export class SeedsModule {}
```

Btw I'm importing my userService into my SharedModule

### 4. Add the SeedsModule into your AppModule

On your AppModule usually at src/app.module.ts add the SeedsModule into `imports`

### Final

If you followed the steps in the nestjs-command repo you should be able to run

```
npx nestjs-command create:user
```

That will bootstrap a new application and run that command and then seed to your mongo/mongoose

Hope that help others too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
I was hoping there was a more native way without another dependency but I 
 will give it a try with nestjs-command too!

Comment: what about bulk insertion ? I know there is a method bulkWrite on mongodb document but how to manage it on typescript using nestjs ?

Comment: How would you, using nestjs-command, make multiple seeds run?
For example, I want to seed everything, using `npx nestjs-command create:all`. 
Of course, I would have to write all seeds before doing it in files as you described above, but I want to run them all with a single command and also to be able to run each one separatedly!

Comment: I think you need to create a separate file for create:all, and inject all your seeders in that file and call corresponding method.

Comment: Hi, stumbled upon this answer, and whanted to check with you, what about using NestJS lifecycle ? It removes dependecies, and you have `onModuleInit()` method which is called before application bootstrap. https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/lifecycle-events

Answer (score 3):

actually you can do it easily with onModuleInit(), here i'm using Mongoose ORM. This all done with zero dependencies, hope it helps

```
import { Injectable, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserRepository } from './repositories/user.repository';

@Injectable()
export class UserService implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(private readonly userRepository: UserRepository) {}

  // onModuleInit() is executed before the app bootstraped
  async onModuleInit() {
    try {
      const res = await this.userRepository.findAll(); // this method returns user data exist in database (if any)
      // checks if any user data exist
      if (res['data'] == 0) {
        const newUser = {
          name: 'yourname',
          email: 'youremail@gmail.com',
          username: 'yourusername',
        };
        const user = await this.userRepository.create(newUser); // this method creates new user in database
        console.log(user);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

  // your other methods
}
```

Comment: worked well for me, thanks! Will update if I find and issues.

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I needed to insert seed during the tests, the best I could find is to create a seed service, imported and used only during tests.

Here is my base class using the schema model, all is needed is to extend and pass the model.

```
// # base.seed.service.ts

import { Model, Document } from 'mongoose';

import { forceArray, toJson } from 'src/utils/code';

export abstract class BaseSeedService<D extends Document> {
  constructor(protected entityModel: Model<D>) {}

  async insert<T = any>(data: T | T[]): Promise<any[]> {
    const docs = await this.entityModel.insertMany(forceArray(data));
    return toJson(docs);
  }
}


// # utils
const toJson = (arg: any) => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arg));
function forceArray<T = any>(instance: T | T[]): T[] {
   if (instance instanceof Array) return instance;
   return [instance];
}


// # dummy.seed.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';

import { DummyDocument } from './dummy.schema';

@Injectable()
export class DummySeedService extends BaseSeedService<DummyDocument> {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Dummy.name)
    protected model: Model<DummyDocument>,
  ) {
    super(model);
  }
}
```

Then inside the tests

```
describe('Dymmy Seeds', () => {
  
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [DummySeedService],
      imports: [
        MongooseModule.forRoot(__connect_to_your_mongodb_test_db__),
        MongooseModule.forFeature([
          {
            name: Dummy.name,
            schema: DummySchema,
          },
        ]),
      ],
    }).compile();

    const seeder = module.get<DummySeedService>(DummySeedService);
    const initData = [__seed_data_here__];
    const entities: Dummy[] = await seeder.insert(initData);
    expect(entities.length > 0).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```